# Data sharing between components in Angular 6

Tags: angular, observable, angular6, behaviorsubject

I have created 2 components and one service as below,

#### component-interaction.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class ComponentInteractionService {

  public dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Test");

  getTestData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
  }

  pustTestData(dataToPush: string): void {
    this.dataSubject.next(dataToPush);
  }
}
```

#### first.component.ts

```js
export class FirstComponent {

  constructor(private componentInteractionService: ComponentInteractionService) { 
    componentInteractionService.getTestData().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log("Received at 1 -- " + data);
    });
  }

  sendTestData(): void {
    this.componentInteractionService.pustTestData("sending data from 1");
  }

}
```

#### second.component.ts

```js
export class SecondComponent {

  constructor(private componentInteractionService: ComponentInteractionService) { 
    componentInteractionService.getTestData().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log("Received at 2 -- " + data);
    });
  }
}
```

**The issue I am currently facing is**

On page load both the components subscribers are being triggered, but when I push data using **sendTestData()** method in **FirstComponent**, only the subscriber in **FirstComponent** is being triggered. The subscriber in **SecondComponent** is not being triggered.
What should I do for both subscribers to get triggered on pushing data using the **sendTestData()** method?

**My Console logs are as below..**

Received at 1 -- Test

Received at 2 -- Test

Received at 1 -- sending data from 1

**Expected Output..**

Received at 1 -- Test

Received at 2 -- Test

Received at 1 -- sending data from 1

Received at 2 -- sending data from 1

Comment: try calling in `ngOnInit()` instead of `constrcutor()`

Comment: I tried this, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Why you have created separate function? You can directly use `dataSubject`, like this : `this.componentInteractionService.dataSubject.subscribe(x=> { console.log(x)});` and call this in your `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example reproducing your problem?

Comment: Note: pushing data method  will not be visible from the second component. you have created behaviorSubject on the dataSubject  so you will recieve the data

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner : I have reproduced it in the below link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwxass?file=src/app/app.componentOne.ts

Comment: Posted an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you provide the same service twice in both `AppComponentOne` and `AppComponentTwo` so they both have different instances of the same service.

Empty `providers` array of both component and provide the service within `app.module.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-distinct-first-component',
  template: '<button (click)="sendTestData()">Click to send Data</button>',
  providers: [ComponentService] // <= remove this line from both components
})
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, 
  FirstComponent, SecondComponent
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ComponentService] // <= provide it here
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks :)
It worked when I imported the service in Parent Component.

Answer (score 0):

working fine for me. check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-capalc)  console

and here is the relevant code

#### common.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

public dataSubject$: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Test");

getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataSubject$.asObservable();
}

setData(dataToPush: string): void{
    this.dataSubject$.next(dataToPush);
 }
}
```

#### first.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-first',
    template: `First Component data`,
})

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
      private commonService: CommonService,
    ) { 

    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.sendCommonData();
      this.getCommonData();
    }

 getCommonData () {
   this.commonService.getData().subscribe(data=> {
        console.log("Received at 1 -- " + data);
    })
 }

sendCommonData() {
    this.commonService.setData("sending data from first");
}

}
```

#### second.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-second',
    template: `Second Component data `,
})

export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
      private commonService: CommonService,
    ) { 

    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.getCommonData();
    }

 getCommonData () {
   this.commonService.getData().subscribe(data=> {
        console.log("Received at 2 -- " + data);
    })
 }


}
```

Comment: It works on load. Not working when I manually push data from one component.
Please check the below example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwxass?file=src/app/app.componentOne.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
 sendTestData(): void {
  this.componentInteractionService.pustTestData("sending data from 1");
  // must call the observable once after adding new data
  this.commonService.getData();
 }
```

You must call the observable after setting new data to the behavior subject.

Comment: Tried. This did not work. 
As I have already called it in constructor, I believe it will already be registered.